# Assign Javascript variable to correct text value of HTML table (The <td> tag)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a PHP file that outputs an HTML table. The table is dynamically created from a list of music videos in a folder. It then outputs my table with the data.

I need to assign a Javascript variable for the td where I am typing to a Javascript function. I window.alert to test the variable but it is blank. I think it is because it doesn't uniquely identify the record I am busy with

How can I uniquely identify the text?

**I have tried:**

```
var y = document.getElementById("about");
var y = document.getElementById("about").value;
var y = document.getElementById("about").innerHTML;
var y = document.getElementById("about").innerText;
```

**It doesn't seem to work, here is my table:**

```
$output .= '<div id="videos-div" class="videos">'."\n";
$output .= '  <table class="stats" cellspacing="5">'."\n";
$output .= ' <tr>'."\n";
$output .= '   <th class="hed" colspan="1">VideoName</td>'."\n";
$output .= '   <th class="hed" colspan="1">Date</td>'."\n";
$output .= '   <th class="hed" colspan="1">Description</td>'."\n";
$output .= ' </tr>'."\n";
```

**Now for each music video I:**

```
$output .= '<tr id="actiontable'.$record['video'].'">'."\n";
$output .= ' <td>'.$videoname.'</td>'."\n";
$output .= ' <td>'.$date.' min</td>'."\n";
$output .= ' <td id="about" ><input type="text" 
oninput="myFunction()" 
placeholder="'.$metadata2.'" /></td>'."\n";
```

**My function:**

```
$output .= '
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction ()
{
var y = document.getElementById("about");
window.alert(y);
}
</script>';
```

When I hardcode the: `window.alert` it does work

What I need to do is take the text from the: Description and then 
    pass that to another `Javascript function`

I don't get any errors, just a `blank variable`. I think it is 
because it doesn't know it is for the td where I am typing

Comment: I thing you need this var y = document.getElementById("about").val(); . I am not sure because i am not on my pc now.

Comment: I am suspecting your JS triggers when the DOM hasn't been loaded. Try to make sure the `$output` is there in the page, and use [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event and see if it works.

Comment: You are getting the parent element of the input, you could do something along those lines : `document.getElementById("about").children[0].value`

Comment: @BoianIvanov it's better to use `getSelector` instead of choosing the first children because HTML can be updated later and this will be difficulte to maintain: `document.getSelector("#about input").value`

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in two place, apply id on input type and second put ' .value ' after you getting about by Id

1. `<input id="about" type="text" oninput="myFunction()" placeholder="'.$metadata2.'" /></td>`
2. `var y = document.getElementById("about").value;`

Comment: Why move the id ? `document.querySelector("#about input").value` works fine

Comment: the id is on the direct parent of the `input` (the `td`) so if he have to handle multiple `td` I will have to handle multi id too.. So your answer add useless complexity

Comment: You can do that, But if you are sure that only Id will apply to these input type and you will have direct access (without any parent child support)

Comment: for multiple access Id will not work. you can have a class that will work.

Comment: Yes... but 1) it's not the question, so you don't have to put this on the answer. 2) Move the id from the td to the input will not fix anything about multiple id. 3) Id and classes are alway better to be on parent than child (to be able to select with JS/CSS the special parent (and so his child)). Because moving the id to the `input` will remove the access to the special `about td`.

Answer (score 0):

**First** you have to be sure that your HTML as been rendered, so go on your console and look that `<td id="about">` is here.

If yes your function with the code under should display something like `[object HTMLTdElement]`.

```
var y = document.getElementById("about");
alert(y);
```

**Second** When you try all of this:

```
var y = document.getElementById("about");
var y = document.getElementById("about").value;
var y = document.getElementById("about").innerHTML;
var y = document.getElementById("about").innerText;
```

It's done on the `<td>` tag, who have the `id`, but you want to do it into the `input` child.
Do it like that:
`var y = document.querySelector("#about input").value`

And it should works !

Comment: I can see:<td id="about"> in my console. When I do getSelector nothing happens and my console error:TypeError: document.getSelector is not a function but when I do:querySelector my alert is empty

Comment: It's `querySelector` and not `getSelector` my bad

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I just realized a different problem. `id`s have to be unique, but you are adding another `about` with every new `<tr>`. Consider using a class-name `about` and a data-attribute with an id for each entry. In the following example I have three rows with buttons for demonstration purposes

```js
function getAboutForId(id) {
  let about = document.querySelector('.about[data-id="'+id+'"] input').value;
  alert(about);
}
```

```html
<div id="videos-div" class="videos">
<table class="stats" cellspacing="5">
<tr>
<th class="hed" colspan="1">VideoName</td>
<th class="hed" colspan="1">Date</td>
<th class="hed" colspan="1">Description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>$videoname</td>
<td>$date min</td>
<td class="about" data-id="1"><input type="text" placeholder="$metadata2" /></td><td><input type="button" value="alert" onclick="getAboutForId(1)"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td>$videoname</td>
<td>$date min</td>
<td class="about" data-id="2"><input type="text" placeholder="$metadata2" /></td><td><input type="button" value="alert" onclick="getAboutForId(2)"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td>$videoname</td>
<td>$date min</td>
<td class="about" data-id="3"><input type="text" placeholder="$metadata2" /></td><td><input type="button" value="alert" onclick="getAboutForId(3)"></td>
</tr>
```

You can then get the input-value from the nested input of the td with this CSS-query: `.about[data-id="1"] input`. It's best to use the `value` attribute with form-elements.

Comment: My alert is empty with: querySelector

Comment: There is another problem. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks.let me try that